# Import-CSV from SharePoint Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, sharepoint, foreach, import-csv

Hoping someone can help with this.

I have a script that runs through multiple site collections and gets a specific CSV file on each site collection. I am throwing the specific CSV URL into an array then wanting to pull data from that CSV and use it in a `foreach`

Here is how I am getting the CSV URL

```
Import-Module "\\path\Connect-SharePoint.psm1"


$SPListConnection = Connect-SharePoint -WebUrl "https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/edmsc/Internal" -CheckForAppCredentials
$SPListWeb = Get-PnPWeb -Connection $SPListConnection
$SPMasterList = Get-PnPList -Connection $SPListConnection -Web $SPListWeb -Identity "Site Collection Central"

$fields = @()
$fields += "ReportLocation"
$fields += "LastRunDate"

$permissionsReports = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()

try {
    $SPMasterListItems = Get-PnPListItem -Connection $SPListConnection -Web $SPListWeb -List $SPMasterList -Fields $fields -ScriptBlock {
        Param($items)

        $SPReportFoldersConnection = Connect-SharePoint -WebUrl "https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/edmsc/Corp/SiteCollectionReports/" -CheckForAppCredentials
        $SPReportFoldersWeb = Get-PnPWeb -Connection $SPReportFoldersConnection

        foreach ($item in $items) {
            try {
                $Report_Location = [string]$item.FieldValues['ReportLocation'].Url
                $LastRunDate = [DateTime]$item.FieldValues['LastRunDate']

                $officeLocation = ($Report_Location -split "/")[-1]
                $report_year = $LastRunDate.Year.ToString()
                $report_month = $LastRunDate.ToString("MMMM")

                $permissionsListLocation = Get-PnPFolderItem -Connection $SPReportFoldersConnection -Web $SPReportFoldersWeb -FolderSiteRelativeUrl "$officeLocation/$report_year/$report_month" -ItemType File
                
                foreach ($item in $permissionsListLocation) {
                    $item.Name
                    $fileURL = "https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/edmsc/Corp/SiteCollectionReports/$officeLocation/$report_year/$report_month/$($item.Name)"

                    if ($item.Name.Contains("permissions")) {
                        $permissionsReports.Add($fileURL)
                        }
                }

            }
            catch {

            }

        }
    }
}
catch {
    #Continue without doing anything
}
```

Now I want to be able to take that array and import each CSV and use the data on there. Is this possible??

When I try this

```
foreach ($item in $permissionsReports) {
      Import-Csv -Path $item
  }
```

I get an error
`Import-Csv : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'https' does not exist.`

EDIT:
Adding output of $permissionReports

```
https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/edmsc/Corp/SiteCollectionReports/BCS/2022/March/bcs-permissions-03-24-2022.csv
https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/edmsc/Corp/SiteCollectionReports/DRR/2022/March/drr-permissions-03-24-2022.csv
https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/edmsc/Corp/SiteCollectionReports/CISR_Analytics/2022/March/cisr_analytics-permissions-03-24-2022.csv
```

Comment: We need to see the entire script. If this is it then you've not defined the parameters correctly.

`-FolderSiteRelativeUrl -
The site relative URL of the folder to retrieve` Based on the documentation is look like this parament needs to be a URL and not a path.

Comment: @anothervictimofthemouse I have updated the script with everything I have

Comment: can you add of a few lines of the `$permissionReports` and also inside that loop can you show me what `$item` looks like?

Comment: @anothervictimofthemouse Added above

Comment: it seems you cannot `import-csv` for a URI. You need to download the file first and then import it. Grabbing a CSV from sharepoint. There's a couple easier ways to do this including just making a local shared drive to the Sharepoint root folder where the files are.